# React - How to cache a functional component and its state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm using `next.js`.

I want to make a simple homepage with a bottom navbar. But when I click the button to switch to another page and then return, the previous page will be re-rendered, and the state of the previous page is lost.

How should I properly tell React to cache my page and it's state.

Here's my code:

`page.tsx`

```js
"use client";

import "./home.scss";
import Index from "./index";
import Hot from "./hot";
import Me from "./me";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function () {
  const [pages, _] = useState(() => {
    console.log("page state");
    return [
      {
        name: "首页",
        node: (() => {
          console.log("generate index");
          return <Index />;
        })(),
      },
      { name: "热榜", node: <Hot /> },
      { name: "我的", node: <Me /> },
    ];
  });
  const [idx, setIdx] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      {pages[idx].node}
      <nav>
        {pages.map((p, i) => (
          <div onPointerUp={() => setIdx(i)} key={i}>
            <p>{p.name}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

`index.tsx`

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function () {
  console.log("index");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(() => {
    console.log("index state");
    return 0;
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>index</p>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`hot.tsx`

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function () {
  console.log("hot");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(() => {
    console.log("hot state");
    return 0;
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>hot</p>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`me.tsx`

```js
"use client";

export default function () {
  console.log("me");
  return (
    <div>
      <p>me</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to store components inside of state in React. For the pages / routing you should take a look at the [Next.js docs: Defining Routes](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes) these will explain how you can setup different routes in your Next app.

Comment: Can I cache the pages corresponding to each route in nextjs?@RubenSmn